# Asyntask in android

Tags: android, multithreading

I am using async task as below. But I need to be able to call a different function inside onPostExecute based on different activities I am using the class below. For example when an activity loads I will use the below class as it is but when user clicks on a listitem in the activity I want to use the same class below but the callback functon needs to be different? Is there a way to do this in android.

```
class PerformOPTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, ServerOutput> {
    // connector=new JSONConnector();
    Connector connector;
    String curUrl;
    ServerOutput currentSO;
    PerformOPTask(String url,ServerOutput serverOutput){
        //connector = new UnitTestConnector();
        connector = new JSONConnector();
        curUrl=url;
        currentSO=serverOutput;
    }

    @Override
    protected ServerOutput doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return connector.getData(URLUtils.getFormattedUrl(curUrl),currentSO);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(ServerOutput output) {
        displayData(output);
        Toast.makeText(BaseFragmentActivity.this, "Done!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can add an interface in the adapter which contains an onComplete method or something like that. You can then add the interface in your constructor of your `AsyncTask`. Like this:

```
public interface OnTaskCompleteListener {
    void onComplete(ServerOuptput output);
}
```

In your `onPostExecute()` you can then just call the `onComplete()`

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In my case I have a super class which calls the async task and also has the displayData method. Then I have a subclass which on loading first time uses the super class logic to populate an array adapter and display data. Now when user clicks on a particular entry I want to use the same async task subclass to fetch data. In this case if I pass instance of my subclass then I won't get any advantage. I was hoping I can somehow make my asynctask call a method which I pass in my constructor or maybe a better way.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass some Object to PerformOPTask(maybe Activity instance for example, or some enumaration, or boolean if there are 2 options)  which will identify who uses this class and which function to call on onPostExecute().

Comment: I think this is easier to implement, and yet extensible *enough* (Maria's solution is more) for the purposes of calling an AsyncTask from multiple classes. Just store that `Activity` reference in an internal member of the AsyncTask class, and use that member as the first Toast parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Both answer are right, you need to inject a dependency for that. And personnaly I prefer to inject them inside the constructor of my own subclasses of AsyncTasks.

The advantages of the solution of @Maria Neumayer is that it will provide something more generic, more abstract and more extensible than using the solution of @narek.gevorgyan